# Would it be appropriate for me to post some questions or answers about disabilities in the workplace?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I haven't seen to many, and the answers all seem to be restricted to

- seek legal advice
- File an ADA action
- They can't do that
- Leave

In fact there are far more options.  The first two are impractical, the third is worthless, and the last shouldn't always be the only viable answer.

Would it be bad form if I asked a question, knowing the different options?  Now, this wouldn't be a hypothetical, but something that actually happened to me.  I also didn't know any better at the time.

So, my question to the community is:

Should I post a question like this, and include some answers of my own if we don't get broad feedback?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314272/839601)

Comment: @gnat  That's not what I'm asking at all.  Is your definition of "duplicate" along the lines of "both posts have words"

Comment: no it is. From what I could tell your background allows to ask and self-answer a really useful question on this topic, and the only risk (well known at sites having more experience with self-answered questions) is that you make some mistake, and the referred post helps to avoid that. BTW I recall a case at SE.SE when expert in particular topic posted a spectacular self-answer as reply to absolutely awful question - back then we managed to salvage it but it was somewhat painful and would want to avoid this here

Comment: @gnat good point.  The hardest part is indeed going to be coming up with the questions.

Comment: Beyond what @gnat said, if you ask and self-answer a question on a "niche" topic "only" because you think it's useful content, there is a very high chance that other people will downvote it (either because they suspect you're just trying to amass reputation "for free", or because they see a threat in not being able to answer themselves, or for lack of imagination on what is a good question for the site even there are few similar ones). So it's better to plan that a significant chunk of the posts will be deleted and that you'll need to pay a reputation cost to do something you believe useful.

Comment: @Nemo I have more than adequate reputation, and disabilities are very common in the workplace.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I post a question like this, and include some answers of my own if we don't get broad feedback?

**I don't see why not**, even more given the fact that [It is ok to ask and answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

When writing a post you even have the option to do so:

[image]

We even have the **self-learner** badge, rewarding users for adding valuable answers to their own question(s).

So I'd say it's perfectly fine to do so. Not only will you be sharing your expertise and knowledge regarding those topics, but will also be generating valuable questions that any other user with experience in the matter can contribute.

This, IMHO, is aligned with the goal of SE of becoming a repository of high-quality Q&A's.

Answer (score 5):

As DarkCygnus [said](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5420/325), self-answers are fine and baked into the system.  One specific point: I'll bet you have some useful information to share that is specific to certain disabilities.  Please do that!  General questions are fine when they're really general, but some disabilities lead to specialized problems, and those questions need some love too.  For example, you'll find some questions related to visual disabilities on the site already (mostly about lighting), and if we don't already have a question about handling large meetings with a hearing disability, that would be a valuable addition.  Mobility limitations pose their own kinds of problems (it's not just about ramps and curb cuts).  I don't know enough about autism to suggest focus areas there, but somebody does.  Etc.

Comment: I know we have at least three regulars with autism, myself included.  I used to do some work with the comission for the blind, and I know plenty about the rest of my disabilities as well, and you are correct,  Some require VERY different accommodations.  I also have some input for psychiatric problems as well.